# Session Timeout on Magnolia CMS

Tags: magnolia

Quick question, I notice that when I login to Magnolia, and didn't touch my browser for some time, It will not auto logout. Is there a configuration for having the session timeout for the Magnolia login?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are deploying Magnolia using Tomcat, then under

> conf/web.xml

You will find the session timeout set to 30 minutes by default. There you may configure it.

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: I tried to change the session-timeout to 2 minutes for testing, but it didnt work. I was not log out in Magnolia. I'm still logged in as the user when I try to change the page or refresh. Is there other configuration that I need to set to achieve this?

Comment: I tested and it worked for me, something is fishy there then. Dummy question but have you restarted your tomcat instance ?

Comment: Yep I restarted. Then I login to the admincentral using the superuser account. Then I dont do anything for a while. Then I try to click on other content app, then it didnt log out automatically but continue to be able to access.

Comment: That's really odd, I am sure it worked for me. I will tomorrow upload a brief video showing it, maybe this would do.

Comment: Oops never mind. I tried the second time then it works already! I dont why the first time it didnt work (I'm 100% sure that I restarted lol). Anyways thanks :)